# JPA model relations

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am currently programming a board for me and my friends with the playframework 1.2.4 that uses the JPA.
Everything was fine until I came to the view mechanism.

The problem is, that every user can have multiple view entries.
Every topic can also have multiple view entries so here is my view model:

```
@Entity
public class ForumTopicView extends Model
{

    @Required
    @ManyToOne
    public ForumTopic   topic;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne
    public User         user;

    @Required
    public Date         viewDate;

}
```

On the other hand, there is only one view for a topic AND the connected user.

Here is my topic model:

```
@Entity
public class ForumTopic extends Model
{

    // ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "topic") // TODO: and the connected user
    public ForumTopicView       view;

    // ...
}
```

How can I customize this that the user has to be the connected user and for every topic only one view selected is.

Thanks for any help!!
MRu

@Yogendra Singh: Yes thats correct. Every user can have a view to one topic.

Comment: One question: If I understand it right, `user` can have multiple `views` (`one-to-many`) but one `view` will be associated with only one  `topic` (`many-to-one`). If so, `user` has multiple `views` and each associated with different `topic`. I believe this is what you want. Is that not right?

Comment: Then what's the problem? In `User`, you can map `views` as `OneToMany`. In `ForumTopicView`, you have already mapped, `topic` as `ManyToOne`.

Comment: The problem is, that ever topic can have onle **one** view for the connected user. And whenever I load the list of topics, the view must be included for this user because i cant fire a second query for each topic in a list with 50 or 100 rows.
You can see that in the topic is a OneToOne relation mappedBy the topic (and there should also be the user) and in the view the topic is in a ManyToOne relation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one side of an association is a ManyToOne, the other side must be a OneToMany, not a OneToOne.

Every topic has multiple views (and one of these views is for the current user). Each user has multiple views (and one of these views is for a given topic). So you have two OneToMany/ManyToOne associations.

It's not clear what you want to do, but I think you'll need to execute a query to get what you want. If what you want is the list of views associated with the current user and corresponding to a given list of topics, the query simply is

```
select view from ForumTopicView view
where view.user = :currentUser
and view.topic in (:listOfTopics)
```

No need for 50 queries if you have 50 topics. The above one retrieves all the views at once.

Comment: The `mappedBy` fields are convenient metadata for doing lazy relation walking, but they don't work for every situation. Sometimes, like JB Nizet is suggesting, you need to use a query.

Comment: Thanks a lot, great help. But how can i relate the query results to the results made in the topic-list?

Comment: Each retrieved ForumTopicView has a ForumTopic. So you could easily build a `Map<ForumTopic, ForumTopicView>` to associate each ForumTopic with its corresponding view, for example.

Comment: Well, I still cannot get this to work how you suggested.
How can I make a relation between View and Topic? Or must I find the view for the topic by iterating over all topics and check whether one is the same? That seems not very comfortable :(

Comment: That's why I suggested building a `Map<ForumTopic, ForumTopicView>`.

Comment: I am new to JPA. Where to put that map?
Will there be a new mysql table created for the map?
Theres only a date in the view that not corresponds to the model relations. Would there be a better solution then?

Comment: You don't put the map anywhere. You define a method taking a list of topics as arguments, which executes the above query, then iterates throught the results, build the map associating the topics in argument with their topic view, and returns it from the method, so that the caller can know which topic view is associated to which topic.